# Pass multiple var to +Add new item SharePoint new form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I HAVE THE FOLLOWING CODE,TO PASS ID FROM PARENT LIST TO A CHILD,I AM LOOKING TO PASS ANOTHER COLUMN VALUE IN THE URL

//get the ID for the Issue from the Query String

`var incidenticketIDICE = getParameterByName("ID");`

`var testColumn = getParameterByName("TestColumn");
var testColumntesttwo = SPUtility.GetSPField(' TestColumn ').GetValue();`

//find the element with the "Add new item" link.
//note that if you have more than one list on your page, this just finds the first one

`var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");`

//modify the "Add new item" link to call the "NewItem2" function and pass in the Issue ID.
//Be sure to put the path to your site below. You can use relative URL to the web application or the FQDN

```
 `function getParameterByName(name){
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
   var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
   var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
   var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
   if(results == null)
     return "";
     else
   return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }`
```

I am looking a way to pass testColumn which I get the value using getParameterByName or testColumntesttwo which I get the value using SPUtility to the anchorElement in addition to ID, I did attempt the folloing $(anchorElement) attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'http://Lists/Test/NewForm.aspx?testIDICE="  + testIDICE + " & " + " testColumn ="  + TestColumn + "');"); BUT it is not passing it to the anchorElement URL,IT ONLY PASS id.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code like below.

```
var incidenticketIDICE = getParameterByName("ID");
var testColumn = getParameterByName("TestColumn");
var testColumntesttwo = SPUtility.GetSPField('TestColumn').GetValue();

var anchorElement = $("a[title='Add a new item to this list or library.']");
$(anchorElement).eq(0).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'https://vaww.vashare.oit.va.gov/sites/OTG/Lists/Call%20Communication%20Event/NewForm.aspx?IncidenticketIDICE="+incidenticketIDICE+"&testColumn="+testColumn+"');");
$(anchorElement).eq(1).attr("href","javascript:NewItem2(event,'https://vaww.vashare.oit.va.gov/sites/OTG/Lists/Call%20Communication%20Event/NewForm.aspx?IncidenticketIDICE="+incidenticketIDICE+"&testColumn="+testColumntesttwo+"');");
```